# Handling Dynamic Column change in Report Builder

Tags: sql, service, report, builder

I have built a report in Report Builder, but it is works only for certain values, i.e a parameter I pass in. I think I know why it is happening, but I'm not sure how to sort it out. 4 of the columns being returned are named dynamically, depending on what the parameter I pass in is.

If I run the report for a different parameter, I get 4 different column names and they are not mapped to the column names the Report Builder uses. 
It seems that Report Builder is only mapping the columns I used when I first tested the query.

Is there a way to specify that certain columns may have different names, and tell Report Builder to expect it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using column name parameters directly in main query.

Make another parameter e.g. COND and fill this parameter in report trigger e.g. after_parameter_form.

```
if  :p_col  is not null then
    :COND := 'AND  :p_col  = :p_token_id' ;
end if;
```

and use in main query as

```
&COND
```